# Trying to store input as a Hashmap in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to store a user input as a hashmap using Ruby. The desired result from this would be (assuming the user inputs, 5,5,N)

position = {"x" => 5; "y" => 5; D => "N"}

```
def rover_position()
  position = {} 
  puts "Please input the rovers X position  "
  position["x"] = gets.chomp
  puts "Please input the rovers Y position  "
  position["y"] = gets.chomp
  puts "Please input the rovers Direction (N,E,S,W)  "
  position["D"] = gets.chomp

end
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rebuild the hash, you've already built it. Just do:

```
def rover_position()
  position = {} 
  puts "Please input the rovers X position  "
  position["x"] = gets.chomp
  puts "Please input the rovers Y position  "
  position["y"] = gets.chomp
  puts "Please input the rovers Direction (N,E,S,W)  "
  position["D"] = gets.chomp
  position
end
```

In console, that looks like:

```
2.3.1 :001 > def rover_position()
2.3.1 :002?>   position = {} 
2.3.1 :003?>   puts "Please input the rovers X position  "
2.3.1 :004?>   position["x"] = gets.chomp
2.3.1 :005?>   puts "Please input the rovers Y position  "
2.3.1 :006?>   position["y"] = gets.chomp
2.3.1 :007?>   puts "Please input the rovers Direction (N,E,S,W)  "
2.3.1 :008?>   position["D"] = gets.chomp
2.3.1 :009?>   position
2.3.1 :010?> end
 => :rover_position 
2.3.1 :011 > 
2.3.1 :012 >   position = rover_position
Please input the rovers X position  
5
Please input the rovers Y position  
5
Please input the rovers Direction (N,E,S,W)  
N
 => {"x"=>"5", "y"=>"5", "D"=>"N"} 
2.3.1 :013 > position
 => {"x"=>"5", "y"=>"5", "D"=>"N"}
```

If you wanted, you could clean that up a little and do something like:

```
def rover_position
  {
    x: "x position",
    y: "y position",
    D: "Direction (N,E,S,W)"
  }.each_with_object({}) do |(key, message), hsh|
    puts "Please input the rovers #{message}"
    hsh[key] = gets.chomp
  end
end
```

Again, in console:

```
2.3.1 :001 > def rover_position
2.3.1 :002?>   {
2.3.1 :003 >     x: "x position",
2.3.1 :004 >     y: "y position",
2.3.1 :005 >     D: "Direction (N,E,S,W)"
2.3.1 :006?>   }.each_with_object({}) do |(key, message), hsh|
2.3.1 :007 >     puts "Please input the rovers #{message}"
2.3.1 :008?>     hsh[key] = gets.chomp
2.3.1 :009?>   end
2.3.1 :010?> end
 => :rover_position 
2.3.1 :011 > position = rover_position
Please input the rovers x position
5
Please input the rovers y position
5
Please input the rovers Direction (N,E,S,W)
N
 => {:x=>"5", :y=>"5", :D=>"N"} 
2.3.1 :012 > position[:x]
 => "5" 
2.3.1 :013 > position[:y]
 => "5" 
2.3.1 :014 > position[:D]
 => "N"
```