# How can I edit a hashmap value from user input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I run the following code I get a set of X,Y keys as well as a Direction key, all assigned a value based on the users input. After this is done, how can I prompt a user that would be able alter the values of the hashmap? Assuming the user inputs x => 1; y => 2; D => N - I would want to alter the x key to become 5, but the other keys must remain unchanged.

Code [as suggested by jvillian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336011/trying-to-store-input-as-a-hashmap-in-ruby/47336253#47336253):

```
def rover_position(position)
  {
    x: "x position",
    y: "y position",
    D: "Direction (N,E,S,W)"
  }.each_with_object({}) do |(key, message), position|
    puts "Please input the rovers #{message}"
    $position[key] = gets.chomp
  end
end
```

Comment: if the user enters 1 for x, how would it become 5? I'm not sure what the problem is with your code is, but a starting point would be to remove the `$` in `$position` .. unlike bash, ruby doesn't prepend the `$` when using variables. When you say `$position` it's actually referring to a global that has never been set. You would get a NoMethodError if not for the fact that references to undefined globals equal `nil`.

Comment: I see you're using the code I provided to your previous question. But, you never accepted that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Ruby variables do not have prefixes, and prefixes have *significant meaning*: `@x`, `$x` and `x` represent three completely different things.

Just do this:

```
position[key] = gets.chomp
```

Or rework your code:

```
PROMPTS = {
  x: "x position",
  y: "y position",
  D: "Direction (N,E,S,W)"
}

def rover_position(position)
  puts "Please input the rovers #{message}"

  PROMPTS.map do |key, message|
    [ key, gets.chomp ]
  end.to_h
end
```

That creates a constant since your prompts don't change from one run to the next, plus avoids the `with_object` fussing.